# How to map new variable in pandas in effective way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
Id  Amount
1   6
2   2
3   0
4   6
```

What I need, is to map : if `Amount` is more than `3` , `Map` is `1`. But,if  `Amount` is less than `3`, `Map` is `0`

```
Id  Amount   Map
1   6        1
2   2        0
3   0        0
4   5        1
```

What I did

```
a = df[['Id','Amount']]
a = a[a['Amount'] >= 3]
a['Map'] = 1
a = a[['Id', 'Map']]
df=  df.merge(a, on='Id', how='left')
df['Amount'].fillna(0)
```

It works, but not highly configurable and not effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert boolean mask to integer:

```
#for better performance convert to numpy array
df['Map'] = (df['Amount'].values >= 3).astype(int)
#pure pandas solution
df['Map'] = (df['Amount'] >= 3).astype(int)
print (df)
   Id  Amount  Map
0   1       6    1
1   2       2    0
2   3       0    0
3   4       6    1
```

**Performance**:

```
#[400000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [133]: %timeit df['Map'] = (df['Amount'].values >= 3).astype(int)
2.44 ms ± 97.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [134]: %timeit df['Map'] = (df['Amount'] >= 3).astype(int)
2.6 ms ± 66.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: @Zero - it is possible, you can find it.

Comment: I guess `@jezrael` answer is faster

Comment: @NabihBawazir - Yes, if want a bit more effective then `df['Map'] = (df['Amount'].values >= 3).astype(int)` should be better